# When one dropdown is opened close another

Tags: jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu, forceclose

I have 2 drop-down menus for a mobile responsive site, one is for blog categories and another for a drop-down search box. These work fine but when you open one, then another it can look a little messy. I have been looking for something that when one is open and a user clicks to open another, listen out and close it. I have had a research and i have found that most functions use 'parent' and 'child' but not sure how it can apply to my snippet of code. I have  also looked into removing classes but nothing seems to do the trick. If anyone has any suggestions to my problem i'd be grateful.

HTML

```
<div id="nav-mobile-responsive"><!--Mobile Navigation-->
        <div class="categories-mobile-responsive">
            <ul id="nav-1">
                <li>
                  <h3></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <?php wp_list_categories('&title_li=') ?>
                    </ul>
                </li> 
           </ul>        
        </div> 
        <div class="searchbar-mobile-responsive">
            <ul id="nav-2">
                <li><h3></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <form method="get" id="searchform-mobile" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
                        <div id="search-inputs">
                        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="search-box" placeholder="SEARCH" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="ref_url" value="<?php esc_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])?>">
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </ul>
                </li> 
           </ul>        
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Javascript to toggle both drop-downs for mobile and small screens:

```
$('.categories-mobile-responsive,.searchbar-mobile-responsive').click(function(){
                $(this).find('ul#nav-1,ul#nav-2').find('ul').slideToggle();
            });

$("#searchform-mobile").click(function(event){ event.stopPropagation(); });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before `$(this).find('ul#nav-1,ul#nav-2').find('ul').slideToggle();`, just slideUp all the other drop down menus.

```
$('.categories-mobile-responsive,.searchbar-mobile-responsive').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().find('ul ul').slideUp();
    $(this).find('ul#nav-1,ul#nav-2').find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

**Extra:** Some bits of code are unnecessary and can be optimized (unless you havn't provided the entire HTML structure - in which case this may break it):

```
$('nav-mobile-responsive div').click(function(){ //only one selector
    $(this).siblings().find('ul ul').slideUp();
    $(this).find('ul ul').slideToggle(); //only call .find() once
});
```

**Source(s)**

[jQuery API - .slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)
[jQuery API - .siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: Should be $('#nav-mobile-responsive ul ul').slideUp().not(this); as nav-mobile-responsive is the ID not the Class. Other than that, nice answer but it doesn't let you hide an already open menu.

Comment: Thanks you're right - I've edited it. And this will hide all open menu's except the one being clicked

Comment: This works fine, but only issue i have is when a slide is open and i want to click and close it so there is none open, it slides back down., cheeky thing!

Comment: Ah, sorry - I got a bit ahead of myself there, thinking `this` was the element being toggled. See my revision above - simpler and WORKS! ;)

Comment: Well thats fantastic, thanks! Just so i understand it, it takes the class of each drop-down menu, listens for a click event for each one, and when it's clicked, the siblings of the other slides up and finds the ul clicked and slides down? I like to know what i am doing and understand it properly, sorry if i am a bit slow, i only do bog standard jQuery! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes - when you click on a div it finds it's siblings, then goes down (with `.find()`) to the `ul`'s that needs to be toggled and slides them up, then it goes down within `this` and `slideToggle()`'s. I have also found some (possibly) redundant code and I have optimised it for you - see my edit :)